# how to test for if mojang api username is invalid in python

Tags: python

when using the mojang api, I havent found a way to test if the username entered is invalid. When you try to send the link with an invalid name you get an error. How would I see if a name is invalid or not?

```
def getInfo(call):
  r = requests.get(call)
  return r.json()

message = 'notavalidign'
mojangurl = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + message
mojanginfo = getInfo(mojangurl)
print(mojanginfo)
```

Comment: check for the response code for both cases e.g. for valid username and invalid username then distinguish between them and evaluate your input

Answer (score 0):

if the username is invalid the r.json() will return a error so all you have to do is simple, you need to use a try except statement and just return true if r.json() does not cause an error and return false if it the r.json() causes an error like this:

```
def ValidUsername(call):
    r = requests.get(call)
    try:
        r.json()
        return True
    except:
        return False


message = 'InvalidIGN'
mojangurl = "https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/" + message
mojanginfo = ValidUsername(mojangurl)
print(mojanginfo)
```